# How do I move bones relative to global position rather than its parent?

Tags: pose-mode

Is there any way I can transform my bone in pose mode relative to the world instead of what it inherited from it's parent in Edit mode?  When I try to do absolute transformations (see red arrow in image), I'd like to zero out everything and have the bone move to 0, 0, 0., but if I zero the transformation it's only relative to parent.

Alternatively, I could use a way to stop a bone from inheriting the move a parent makes between Edit mode and Pose mode.  I already know about dis-selecting "inherit rotation" and "inherit scale" but I still need my bone to inherit those things, just not the move from edit to pose.

For background, I'm taking already created models that have already had their pose and edit positions created, and I'm just trying to modify/add to them.

Oh, and one other way I could solve my problem is if I could parent my bone in Pose mode instead of Edit mode.

[image: My pic]

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is, instead of parenting your bone, you could use a "Child Of" constraint on it. You can animate its influence during your animation.

And if you want to push this further, you can even have its influence driven by a controller, parented to your bone.